# weighted normal equations derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am working my way through the book "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" By Gilbert Strang and I can't seem to arrive at the same equation he does for weighed normal equations which he gives as

$$
(A^TW^TWA)\hat{x}_W = A^TW^TWb
$$

the general equation for a weighted system is given

$$ 
WAx = Wb 
$$

the least squares solution (the closest point in the column space to $Wb$ would be

$$
p = WA\hat{x}
$$

and the error vector in the left nullspace (orthogonal to the column space ) is $e = Wb-p$. I know the solution to $WA\hat{x}$ must be in the orthogonal left nullspace and therefore we could solve

$$
W^TA^T(Wb - WA\hat{x}) = 0
$$

but when I rearrange this I just distribute it and get stuck as to where to go. I arrive at

$$
W^TA^TWb - W^TA^TWA\hat{x} = 0
$$

I can see that I have all of the proper parts of the equation, but mine looks different than his and I am not sure how to arrive at his. What should I do differently?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Strang's equation, set 
$\;F\!=\!WA,\;g\!=\!Wb\;$
to obtain
$$\eqalign{
&(A^TW^T)\,(WA)x = (A^TW^T)\,(Wb) \\
&(F^TF)x = F^Tg \\
}$$
The least-squares solution to this system is 
$$x = (F^TF)^{-1}F^Tg$$
assuming $(F^TF)^{-1}$ exists.

If the inverse does not exist, then the solution can be written as
$$x=F^+g + (I-F^+F)y$$
where $F^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse, $\,\big(I-F^+F\big)\,$ is the nullspace projector, and $y$ is an arbitrary vector.